# syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TEXT or FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '('

Tags: mysql, percona

I have many messages like the following in /var/log/mysqld.log
What does it mean?

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%$
    syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TEXT or FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '('
    syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TEXT or FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '('
    syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TEXT or FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '('
    syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TEXT or FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '('
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%$
```

centos 6.4
Server version: 5.6.12-56 Percona Server (GPL), Release rc60.4, Revision 393

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a syntax error in a query involving [Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using innoDB, your FT query to match/against probably includes this special character: `*`. 
See this bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78485